# Change print settings if there is more than 1 set of data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My rpt file is designed to fit on A5 paper. When more than one set of data is found, I need to print two of them on one sheet of A4 paper. How can I handle this?

I'm using Crystal Report with VB.net on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Is the report being populated from a data source? If so, you can check how many rows fit in an A5 paper. If the rows of your data source exceeds the number of rows use a different report (the one with A4 paper), else use the report with A5 paper.

Comment: You mean I have to design 2 rpt file and check the number of row before using?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.